# PyQt: how to edit item in itemmodel?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

I have QStandardItemModel in a tree and I need to edit some item.
I need make the same action, what user can do by double click.

Items are editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **start editing** of an item, you need call this slot of the view (not the model!):

```
myView.edit(index);
```

You can also **set the new value** directly via `QAbstractItemModel.setData`. The role for this defaults to `Qt.EditRole` which is the same role used by the views when editing has been finished:

```
myModel.setData(index, newValue);
```

where `index` references the item you want to edit.

You can **create such a `QModelIndex`** by asking the model:

```
myModel.index(row, column); # for a root item
myModel.index(row, column, parent); # for a children of "parent"
```

So, for example, if you want to set the third item in the second root item to "foo", write:

```
index1 = myModel.index(2, 1);
index2 = myModel.index(3, 1, index1);
myModel.setData(index2, "foo");
```

Comment: I dont want to change data, just take focus on the item and show which item will be changed by writing (the same can you make by double click on the item, no more, no changes - its users part)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. I just updated my answer and added the answer to your question at the top. I didn't remove the rest of the answer as it might help future readers.

Comment: GREAT! It works, but if I call this edit function from slot itemChanged(QStandardItem *), I get error "edit: editing failed". How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I can't help you with that. When I understood you correctly, you want to trigger the edit operation when an item in your model has been changed. I see a problem in that: When the edit operation is done, the item changes => infinite loop.

Comment: I dont wnat to change items. Just start editing to show user what can he change by typing. Thanks for helping, I get the same code in dataChanged slot from proxy_model and it works. I cant explain why are there troubles with model. But its ok for me, now :-)